# Enlarge TextView's Width according to a string length

Tags: android

I have a ListView with multiple TextViews with different width.

Example:

```
Column1 | Column2 
text    | texttext 
text    | texttexttext
```

Here is a picture describing the design I want:[image]

If I set a `width` from *Column2* and that string (here *Manchester City*) will not fit into the `width` I set I get the display from the left (*ACTUAL DISPLAY*).

Is it possible to set *Column2's* width value as the max length from all the values I have in the TextViews?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add the single line property to the text view in every raw to ensure that the text will remain in a single line

```
android:singleLine="true"
```

then set the width of the text view and the list to wrap content to ensure that the text view width fits the text and to ensure that the width of the list fits the width of the largest text view

```
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
```

Answer (score 1):

Although you can use the attribute `android:singleLine` as [Ahmed Rajab suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48422418/4070469), it's [deprecated sinde API 3](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#singleLine). So I'd rather solve this as it's suggested on the docs:

> Use **maxLines** instead to change the layout of a static text, and use
>   the textMultiLine flag in the inputType attribute instead for editable
>   text views (if both singleLine and inputType are supplied, the
>   inputType flags will override the value of singleLine).

Use both `android:maxLines="1"` and `android:layout_width="wrap_content"` and you'll be good to go.

Answer (score 0):

Add to your textview in layout, your text will be displayed in one line.

```
android:singleLine="true"
```

Use fixed width for textview to make them similar.

```
android:layout_width="(number)dp"
```

Hope my answer will help.

Comment: Yes, I thought about that, but unfortunately that means I'll have a limit to the text's length in my opinion.

Comment: @grrigore Try to use constraint layout, first of all, that way you'll be able to make you width similar, secondly, there definitely won't be character limits

Comment: if I set singleLine = true, assuming my text is way longer that the width of that TextView from an input like _texttexttext_ I'll have _texttex.._ that's what I meant to say with the character limit